# issue with numpy arrays while curve fitting with scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a Cosine curve but I get an error regarding the shape of my arrays. The error only appears when I change the np.cos(phi - delta) to np.cos(2*phi - delta).

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import math
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([-5,0])
#bond CHARMM
def func(phi, kphi, delta):
     return kphi * (1 + np.cos(2*phi - delta))



class Dihedral:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.masses = {'H': 1, 'D': 2, 'C': 12, 'O': 16} 

    def Dihedral_fit (self,x,y):

        self.popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0 =(0,2.3),method='trf')
        print "Cosine fit"
        print  self.popt

        plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

        diff=sum(abs(func(x,self.popt[0],self.popt[1])-y))/len(x)
        print "AAE is"
        print diff
        plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *self.popt), 'r-',label='Cos: kphi=%5.3f, delta=%5.3f' % tuple(self.popt))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    xdata = [0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105]
    ydata = [-4.24,-3.82,-3.08,-2.07,-1.04,-0.30,0,-30]
    x = np.array(xdata)
    y = np.array(ydata) 
    Harm=Dihedral()
    Harm.Dihedral_fit(x,y)

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

any help will be grateful

Comment: You should show the error.  Others identifed the issue without that, but the full error would have the problem more obvious to the rest of us.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the last line of `Dihedral_fit`. You are passing a list as first argument to `func` and as Yaroslav pointed out a multiplication of a list with a constant yields a list which is the repetition of the original list. So exchange `xdata` with `x`, which is a numpy array and the code should run as expected. Nevertheless, the model is not a good description of your data. You should add a fitting parameter for the period of the oscillation.

**EDIT:**

When allowing the period to adjust I get nice results (omitting the last point, which seems to be an outlier).

[image]

But the success of the fit depends very much (as always) on a good initial guess.

Here is is modified code:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import math
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([-5,0])
#bond CHARMM
def func(phi, kphi, om, delta):
     return kphi * (1 + np.cos(om*phi - delta))



class Dihedral:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.masses = {'H': 1, 'D': 2, 'C': 12, 'O': 16} 

    def Dihedral_fit (self,x,y):
        self.popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=(-3,.03,0), method='trf')
        print "Cosine fit"
        print  self.popt

        plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='data')

        diff=sum(abs(func(x,*self.popt)-y))/len(x)
        print "AAE is"
        print diff
        plt.plot(x, func(x, *self.popt), 'r-',label='Cos: kphi=%5.3f, delta=%5.3f, om=%5.3f' % tuple(self.popt))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xdata = [0,15,30,45,60,75,90]
    ydata = [-4.24,-3.82,-3.08,-2.07,-1.04,-0.30,0]
    x = np.array(xdata)
    y = np.array(ydata) 
    Harm=Dihedral()
    Harm.Dihedral_fit(x,y)

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: 2* was a mathematical operation, I was not trying to extend the list, ... .the issue is python does not have cos function using math.cos also broke the code so I just tried the np.cos which now I see is doing something else

Comment: The result of the multiplication of the list by a factor of 2 does not depend on whether you use ``math.cos`` or ``np.cos``. Only when multiplying a ``np.array`` by a factor you will get what you expect, as you say: a mathermatical operation.

Comment: can you please share the code you used? to get this plot?

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying list by 2:

```
xdata = [0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105]
res = 2*xdata
```

and so

```
res = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105]
```

Either rework your code or use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

...

#xdata = [0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105]
xdata = pd.Series([0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105])
```